# Using #define in VS debugger: any way to hover and see values?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, debugging, c-preprocessor

I am writing a **C** app using VS2010.  I have the following #define:

```
#define wRow   Wksp[Session.wkspIndex]->Row
```

"Row" is an array of structures.  So without the defines, it looks like this:

```
Wksp[Session.wkspIndex]->Row[1].value
```

Without the define, I can hover over "value" and see its value.
But when I use the define, like this:

```
wRow[1].value
```

then hovering does nothing at all because (I assume) the debugger is too lazy to do the expansion that I defined.

Is there any way to tell the debugger to expand the `#define` so I can see its value?  The same problem appears in the Watch window: I cannot enter `wRow...` but must use `Wksp[Session.wkspIndex]->Row...`.

Comment: I think you should read the link to see how to efficiently debug macro in VS [**How to debug macros efficiently in VS**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389838/how-to-debug-macros-efficiently-in-vs). It gives at lease a reasonal way to expand the macro code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you are asking how to get the value of this define:
[image: hovering in debug mode without define]

the same way you would get the value of this variable:
[image: hovering in debug mode with define]

In Visual Studio 2010, you can not get the value of a macro at debug time the same way you would get the value of a variable. Hovering over a variable actually has the same effect as entering the variable in the watch window, and this watch window is limited in what information it can access because of the format of Visual Studio debug symbols. If you enter the macro `vRow` in the watch window, you will get:

> Error: symbol "vRow" not found

which is why nothing is shown when you hover over `vRow`.

To debug macro values with Visual Studio, you can set `Preprocess to a file` to yes in `Configuration Properties ->C/C++ ->Preprocessor`. Then the next time you compile your program Visual Studio will generate a .i file, which is the output of the preprocessor. By opening this .i file, you can see what is the actual expanded value of your macro, and enter this value in the watch window while you are debugging.

Comment: Note that the `Preprocess to a file` option prevents an object file being generated, so you can't just leave it switched on.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx

Comment: @RichieHindle I know, but I don't know of any option to generate a preprocessed file and an object file at the same time in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend using temporary pointer instead. They work a lot better with 
debuggers, and also respect the scope.

Something like:

```
void myFunc(void) {
    RowType * wRow = Wksp[Session.wkspIndex]->Row;
    wRow[1].value = 0; /* or whatever */
}
```

Comment: With the #define, the value of `wRow` changes as the value of `Session.wkspIndex` changes. With your variable, it doesn't.

Comment: @RichieHindle If `Session.wkspIndex` can change, that is even more reason to use pointer which is refreshed instead. Using preprocessor will make it hard to follow the code, as index change is hidden behind the macro. There are uses for preprocessor, but this isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a compiler option to ease your debug...

```
#ifdef _DEBUG

<TYPE> *wRow = Wksp[Session.wkspIndex]->Row;

#else

#define wRow Wksp[Session.wkspIndex]->Row

#endif
```

Comment: Your two alternatives aren't the same - with the `#define`, the value of `wRow` changes as the value of `Session.wkspIndex` changes.  With the plain variable, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux simply use GDB and his expand macros capabilities

On windows I use https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/ integrated into Visual Studio

Configuration Properties ->C/C++ ->Preprocessor->>YES also works but it is overkilling.